# Dealing with game states with different resources in C

Tags: c, pointers, state-machine

I am trying to write a simple game to see how it's done. In my current implementation, I am using array of function pointer's, and my main game loop (stripped) looks like this;

```
while (stateid != STATE_EXIT) {
    handle_events[stateid] ();
    logic[stateid] ();
    render[stateid]();
    change_state(); // change state id, and load new state
}
```

This way, I can call different functions, depending on the game state. A game state may be something like title, menu or level1 etc. Since each state has different resources, I also have load, and unload functions for each state, here is how `change_state` looks (stripped)

```
if (nextstate != STATE_NULL) {
    unload_level[stateid] ();
    load_level[nextstate]();
    stateid = nextstate;
    nextstate = STATE_NULL;
}
```

To handle different resources on different game states, I have made a global void pointer. This global may point to a `struct game` or `struct title` depending on the game state. For example, when load_level[STATE_TITLE] is called, a `struct title` gets created, and global void pointer is set to it's address. So, game state functions can use it like this:

```
void logic_game()
{
    struct game *resources = (struct game *) globalvoidpointer;
    // do stuff with resources...
}
```

But, this whole thing doesn't feel right. It feels overengineered and compilcated to me. How would you suggest I should manage game resources and states? (or say so if this is not overly complicated, and I should stick with it.)

Comment: Perhaps a question for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the design is over-thought.

Set this aspect of the architecture aside for awhile.  Then put some effort into sketching out what two different `stateid` implementations will do for `handle_events()`, `logic()`, and `render()`.  You will probably discover that abstractions for resources are not necessary.  The `stateid` itself is probably more than enough to distinguish between what needs to be done.